# How to save DetailPrint command message in file in NSIS Script?

Tags: deployment, nsis

Idea is to run a NSIS script in silent mode to a remote machine and once installation is successfully done than get the log file back to host machine.

I have lots of `Detailprint` command messages that show the progress of the script. Now question is how am i gonna save these messages to the log file. I was looking into this http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Dump_log_to_file but it says it wont work in silent mode.

Answer (score 5):

I use this method to save logs. I don't know if this the best method but it works well for me.

```
!ifndef DEBUG_MODE
  !define DEBUG_MODE true
!endif

!define LOGFILE "$TEMP\my_logfile.log"

!if ${DEBUG_MODE} == true
  !define DetailPrint '!insertmacro _debugMsg'
!else
  !define DetailPrint '!insertmacro _nodebugMsg'
!endif

!macro _debugMsg MSG
  push $3
  push $2
  push $1
  push $0
  push $R0

  strcpy $R0 "${MSG}"

  ClearErrors
  FileOpen $1 ${LOGFILE} a
  FileSeek $1 0 END
  IfErrors +8
  ${GetTime} "" "L" $0 $0 $0 $0 $0 $2 $3
  FileWrite $1 "$0:$2:$3$\t"
  FileWrite $1 "${__FUNCTION__}$\t"
  FileWrite $1 "$R0"
  FileWrite $1 "$\t(${__FILE__},${__FUNCTION__},${__LINE__})"
  FileWrite $1 "$\n"
  FileClose $1

  pop $R0
  pop $0
  pop $1
  pop $2
  pop $3
!macroend

!macro _nodebugMsg _MSG
  ;you can put here nothing or you can put the regular DetailPrint
  DetailPrint "${MSG}"
!macroend
```

After that you just have to find and replace DetailPrint with ${DetailPrint}

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, the listview window does not exist in silent mode.

I guess you have two options, roll your own logging:

```
var hFileLog
!macro Log_Init logfile
FileOpen $hFileLog "${logfile}" w ;Or "a" for append
!macroend
!macro Log_String msg
DetailPrint "${msg}"
FileWrite $hFileLog "${msg}$\r$\n"
!macroend
!macro Log_Close
FileWrite $hFileLog 'Done.'
FileClose $hFileLog
!macroend
!macro File src
File "${src}"
FileWrite $hFileLog 'Extracting "${src}" to $outdir$\r$\n'
!macroend

Section "Main Program"
!insertmacro Log_Init "$instdir\install.log"
!insertmacro Log_String "Starting install..."

SetOutPath $instdir
!insertmacro File "${__FILE__}"
SectionEnd

Section "Optional Foo Component"
!insertmacro Log_String "Installing Foo"
SectionEnd

Section
!insertmacro Log_Close
SectionEnd
```

or add more hacks to make DumpLog work:

```
Function .onInit
IfSilent 0 +2
StrCpy $0 1 ;We need to know if we are in "real silent" mode
SetSilent normal ;Turn off real silent mode so we can fake it
FunctionEnd

Function .onGuiInit
StrCmp $0 1 0 +3
HideWindow
SetSilent silent ;The docs say this is only supported in .onInit but all we care about is the internal flag used by IfSilent
FunctionEnd

LicenseData "${__FILE__}"
page license skipifsilent ; All pages except instfiles needs this hack
page directory skipifsilent
page instfiles

Function skipifsilent
IfSilent 0 +3
HideWindow
Abort
FunctionEnd

Section
IfSilent 0 +2
HideWindow

SetOutPath $instdir
File "${__FILE__}"
Sleep 2222 ;So we can see that it is hidden and not just finishing quickly


DetailPrint "$(^Completed)" ; Fake the completed message show it shows in the log
Push "$EXEDIR\install.log"
Call DumpLog

IfSilent 0 +2
Quit
SetDetailsPrint textonly
SectionEnd

!define LVM_GETITEMCOUNT 0x1004
!define LVM_GETITEMTEXT 0x102D

Function DumpLog
  Exch $5
  Push $0
  Push $1
  Push $2
  Push $3
  Push $4
  Push $6

  FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
  GetDlgItem $0 $0 1016
  StrCmp $0 0 exit
  FileOpen $5 $5 "w"
  StrCmp $5 "" exit
    SendMessage $0 ${LVM_GETITEMCOUNT} 0 0 $6
    System::Alloc ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
    Pop $3
    StrCpy $2 0
    System::Call "*(i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i) i \
      (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, r3, ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}) .r1"
    loop: StrCmp $2 $6 done
      System::Call "User32::SendMessageA(i, i, i, i) i \
        ($0, ${LVM_GETITEMTEXT}, $2, r1)"
      System::Call "*$3(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN} .r4)"
      FileWrite $5 "$4$\r$\n"
      IntOp $2 $2 + 1
      Goto loop
    done:
      FileClose $5
      System::Free $1
      System::Free $3
  exit:
    Pop $6
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
    Exch $5
FunctionEnd
```